# In edit mode, there is an origin located off the side of it's face. It ends up clumping everything together when subdivided. How do I fix this please?

Tags: edit-mode, subdivision-surface, origin

The meshes clump together when subdivided:

[image: The meshes clump together when subdivided.]

The origin is off of the face:

[image: The origin is off of the face.]

Comment: Please do provide either the blend file or a screenshot from the bottom side.
From experience I would guess that the bottom is one big polygon, which you would need to cut into smaller faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because of the face at the bottom that is not visible to us. Subdivision Surface modifier divides concave face like that - this is normal. If you wish to avoid that you should divide the bottom face so it consists of a few convex faces instead of one concave face.

[image]